# Matrix in footnote

Tags: matrices

I want to insert a matrix in footnotes, my paper has two columns and the footnote goes under one of the columns. How can I put the footnote under the whole page?

[image]

This is my code, I'm writing in an IEEE conference template.

```
\footnote[1]{ 
    \begin{equation} 
    A_{ST}=\begin{bmatrix} A_{PLL}+\begin{bmatrix} B_{1PLL}T_V^{-1} && 0 \end{bmatrix} && [0]_{2*2} && [0]_{2*2} && [0]_{2*3} \\ \begin{bmatrix} B_{1v}T_V^{-1} && 0 \end{bmatrix} && [0]_{2*2} && [0]_{2*2} && B_{2v}\\ \begin{bmatrix} B_{1c}D_{1v}T_V^{-1} && 0 \end{bmatrix}&& B_{1c}C_v && [0]_{2*2} && B_{1c}D_{2v}+B_{2c}\\ B_{3F}C_PLL+\\ \begin{bmatrix} (B_{1F}D_{1c}D_{1v}+B_{1F}D_{2c} +\\B_{2F}+B_{3F}D_{PLL})T_V^{-1} && 0 \end{bmatrix} && B_{1F}D_{1c}C_v && B_{1F}C_c && A_F+\\ && && &&B_{1F}D_{1c}D_{2v}+B_{1F}D_{3c} \end{bmatrix} 
    \end{equation}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please post your code? More specifically, please provide a minimal working example, that is a snippet, as small as possible, to reproduce your problem?

Comment: \footnote[1]{
\begin{equation}
A_{ST}=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{PLL}+\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1PLL}T_V^{-1} && 0
\end{bmatrix} && [0]_{2*2} && [0]_{2*2} && [0]_{2*3}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1v}T_V^{-1} && 0
\end{bmatrix} && [0]_{2*2} && [0]_{2*2} && B_{2v}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1c}D_{1v}T_V^{-1} && 0
\end{bmatrix}&& B_{1c}C_v && [0]_{2*2} && B_{1c}D_{2v}+B_{2c}\\
B_{3F}C_PLL+\\ \begin{bmatrix}
(B_{1F}D_{1c}D_{1v}+B_{1F}D_{2c} +\\B_{2F}+B_{3F}D_{PLL})T_V^{-1} && 0
\end{bmatrix} && B_{1F}D_{1c}C_v && B_{1F}C_c && A_F+\\ && && &&B_{1F}D_{1c}D_{2v}+B_{1F}D_{3c}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}}

Comment: this is my code, I'm writing in an IEEE conference template.

Comment: I inserted your comments to this question into the question above. Please edit your question to add more code or information. Your code only represents the footnote, but not the rest of your document. It seems that the footnote is alright, but the positioning is wrong. So, please provide a compilable MWE that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.